# Географические координаты в координаты карты

Tags: c++, алгоритм, qt

Есть идеи (или готовое решение), как перевести долготу и ширину в координату картинки карты мира:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Язык реализации не столько важен, но лучше с++ и qt. И совсем хорошо будет, если показать в реализации с библиотекой QWT.

Comment: Вам нужно разобраться, как называется эта проекция. А потом уже поискать алгоритм перевода. Но, если карта будет такой маленькой, то возможно, даже табличный метод будет работать на ура. А также крайне желательно раздобыть книгу А. А. Зализняка.

Comment: посмотрите библиотеку proj4 (http://proj4.org/) Но да, сначала надо определиться с тем, какая проекция вам требуется

Comment: Любая карта - это проекция эллипсоида на плоскость . Проекции бывают разные - азимутальные, цилиндрические, конические,круговые, псевдоконические, псевдоцилиндрические, поликонические - и это только классификация по виду меридианов и параллелей нормальной сетки. А ещё по положению полюса нормальной системы координат - полярные, поперечные и  косые (наклонные), а также по способу использования - сплошные, многополосные, многогранные и составные. В вашем случае рискну предположить, что это псевдоцилиндрическая поперечная проекция.

Comment: Похоже на один из вариантов проекций Эккерта

Comment: Долгота и широта тоже бывают разные, в зависимости от эллипсоида. Обычно берут долготу и широту на исходном эллипсоиде, переводят их в долготу и широту на `WGS84`, а потом в плоские прямоугольные координаты требуемой проекции. [proj4](http://proj4.org) (указанный выше) должен в этом помочь. Зная плоские прямоугольные координаты Вы сможете перевести их в координаты картинки.

Comment: Долгота и широта -- это геодезические координаты, а не географические.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для преобразования геодезических координат в декартовы выбранной картографической проекции и обратно можно использовать популярную библиотеку proj4 (proj4.org).